# Understanding Definition of Continuity and Variable Substitution in Limits

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

The formal definition of continuity of a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is that $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, \lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) =f(a)$.

Using the definition of the limit, in delta epsilon terms, the definition for continuity as expressed above is:
$\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$.

**Question 1** - about variable substitution in limits:

I know that 
$\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$
is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{y\to 3} f(y-3+a)$ by intuition. What formally allows us to do this sort of variable substitution? More specifically, what Theorem allows us to change $x \rightarrow a$ to $y \rightarrow 3$ when dealing with limits?

I ask because it seems like many limits problems require some clever substitution of variables in order to proceed solving them.

**Question 2**

If it's indeed valid to do the variable switch in Question 1, is it then correct to to say that these definitions of continuity are equivalent:

Statement 1:

$\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$

and
Statement 2:

$\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0, \forall y-3 \in \mathbb{R}, |y-3-a| < \delta \implies |f(y-3)-f(a)| < \epsilon$

and
Statement 3:

$\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}, |y-3-a| < \delta \implies |f(y-3)-f(a)| < \epsilon$

(here, i'm just saying if the implication works for $y-3 \in \mathbb{R}$, it would also work for $y \in \mathbb{R}$)

**Question 3**

Here is where I get a little confused. Suppose now $f$ is defined as $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is just a closed interval on the real number line.

I suspect $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=\lim\limits_{y\to 3} f(y-3+a)$ for $a \in X$ is still true.

But, when I examine the delta-epsilon, it seems like something breaks down. It seems like when going from Statement 2 to Statement 3, it doesn't hold.

Statement 2* with $X$ as domain instead of $\mathbb{R}$:

$\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0, \forall y-3 \in X, |y-3-a| < \delta \implies |f(y-3)-f(a)| < \epsilon$

and
Statement 3* with $X$ as domain instead of $\mathbb{R}$:

$\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0, \forall y \in X, |y-3-a| < \delta \implies |f(y-3)-f(a)| < \epsilon$

because if $y-3$ is in $X$, it doesn't imply $y$ is in $X$.

If the variable substitution with limits can be done, shouldn't the delta-epsilon agree? Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: For your Q1 (Q2 TL; DR): if $x \mapsto \varphi(x)$ has limit $a$ as $x \to b,$ and $x \mapsto f(x)$ has limit $L$ as $x\to a,$ then the composite function $x \mapsto f(\varphi(x))$ ("obtained by substituting the variable $x$ for the variable $\varphi(x)$") has limit $L$ as $x \to b.$

Comment: The corresponding $\epsilon, \delta$ statement for second limit is $\forall a\in X, \forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta >0,\forall y-3+a\in X, |y-3|<\delta\implies |f(y-3+a)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. Btw the key to understanding limits is not to write the definition using logical symbols bur rather to write/understand it in your natural language.

Comment: Writing the logical statements precisely is not easy and you have clearly made a mistake.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, Going from Statement 1 to Statement 2, I am merely substituting $x=y-3$. This should be valid, no?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I understand how to write $\lim\limits_{y\to 3} f(y-3+a)$ as delta epsilon. What I want to understand, is how to go from one delta epsilon to the other.

Comment: First of all substitution in limits is not the same as substituting in limit definition. Rather you should see a proof of the substitution rule: if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =L, \lim_{x\to b} g(x) =a$ and $g(x) \neq a$ as $x\to b$ then $\lim_{x\to b} f(g(x)) =L$.

Comment: Further the substitution here is $x=y-3+a$ and not $x=y-3$.

Comment: Also remember that manipulation of limits is not mechanical symbol shunting in logical statements. You need to understand the logical statements clearly and frame arguments in your mind. It is better to avoid writing symbols like $\forall,\exists$ altogether and instead write in English.